# JBoss Fuse v6.2 - Tracing

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

What is the way to do message tracing for each request made to the JBoss Fuse 6.2 server? In my case most of the entry points are CXF REST service with the processing delegated to Camel routes in some cases. I would like to do end-to-end tracing with same message id that can correlate the request processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, there was a similar requirement. Customer wanted to see all e2e log by executing grep command to system logs with a transaction id.

I used `CXF interceptors` and `MDC logging` capability for this as below:

1. Create a common CXF request and response interceptors. Add them to all your Camel's CXF Server/Client configuration
2. With your request interceptor, extract transaction id from request (or generte it yourself) then put it into MDC map. MDC is a thread local variable that `log4j, slf4j`,.. uses.
3. Print request, it'll have your transaction id as prefix thanks to MDC.
   Dont forget to add your MDC key in logging format configuration
4. All logs you print until the end of operation with this transaction Id until the end. 
   If you're always using `direct-vm, direct` for routing then it wont be problem. However as you may know using `seda, multi` processing, etc. your execution is handled by other threads. Since MDC is thread local variable, you need to manually handle the trouble by transferring it.
5. With your response interceptor, log response message then clear MDC values.
6. If you're using CXF as client, you should use same interceptor approach to be able to print client request/reponses with transaction id.

See [CXF-RS](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) and [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) links as entry points

Comment: I would accept this answer. However, we did it little differently since my requirement to send events to external BAM solution and to trace it at a deeper level at different steps of execution. So we came up with a component to send JMS event from each point of execution that needs to be monitored and then that event was further processed and sent over to the BAM. The MDC literature inspired me to adopt the ThreadLocal approach to store the common elements of the event. It is working as expected. I will update this thread with future posts if there needs to be any adjustment to this design.

Comment: Thanks. I'd recommend using exchange's properties for your common objects. Since exchange is copied on some conditions like splits, thread changes (vm, seda,etc) put a concurrent map in there and use it. Otherwise when e.g. split done you'll lose it on caller side. It's safer than threadlocal, you'll be sure all are cleaned up when finished. With threadlocal, on next request processing you'll have old executions data which may cause issues.

Comment: @dave, can you please elaborate your approach as I really understood your point.